# Single file, being written by multiple users in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have multiple users logged in at the same time, and they can write the same file simultaneously.
How can I prevent collision for a file when multiple users are writing on a single file in nodejs.

Comment: please share your use case

Comment: basically, in my system many users are logged in at the same time, and they change things on the screen, which are sent to the server via web-sockets, all of those changes must be saved in a single file. So I have to accept (at the server side) whatever changes users make. Actually I have to append each of those changes in to a single file. But I can not simply write on the file, as there is a probability that the file is already being written. So may be I have to see for a queue sort of thing, where my file is updated based on which request came first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have one node process the simples solution would be to use `fs.writeFileSync`.

The proper way to do it is to use [rwlock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rwlock) to properly lock file so that only one process at a time can write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `fs.writeFileSync` will block the event loop and will block the rest of your asynchronous functions in the Node event queue. Another and better approach is to use a module like `semaphore`.

```
var sem = require('semaphore')(1);
var server = require('http').createServer(req, res) {
    res.write("Start your file write sir");

    sem.take(function() {
        // Process your write to file using fs.writeFile
        // And finish the request
        res.end("Bye bye, your file write is done.");
        sem.leave();
    });
});
```

It will block any other HTTP request, without blocking entire event loop, don't forget be asynchronous ever !

Comment: basically, in my system many users are logged in at the same time, and they change things on the screen, which are sent to the server via web-sockets, all of those changes must be saved in a single file. So I have to accept (at the server side) whatever changes users make. 
Do I need some extra thing or will the bottom code would work fine?
        //on the server side I have some thing like this:    
        socket.on('newObject', function(data){
              fs.writeFileSync (......);    //data is added to the file.
         }